# Change RSS name for Yahoo pipe

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I use Yahoo Pipes to filter my tech news RSS feeds. I run the pipe serveral times with different feed URLs via the User Input module.

Here is the pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ba198dc1578c5146478f2592bfba9ff9

Now when I subscribe to the pipe output via Feedly, it always shows the Pipe title instead of the RSS feed name. See here:

[image: Feedly showing Pipe title]

I already renamed the feed in Google Reader and/or Feedly but it doesn't affect the title display when I select the feed.
My question is: how do I change the title of the output RSS feed?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the title in Pipes.